# Rename files with foldername and exclusions using powershell

Tags: powershell, pdf, subdirectory, batch-rename

There are lots of topics with the same title, but trying/mending them all to fit my needs is so far unsuccessful.

This came close to what I want to achieve, but the exclude is not working, it renames the PDF files in all subfolders instead of the only remaining folder “Folder 3”. Also here I tried solutions from other topics of which none worked for me so far.

```
[string[]]$Path = @('C:\test\')
[string[]]$Excludes = @('*folder 1*', '*Folder 2*')
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | ?{$_.DirectoryName -notlike $Excludes } | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.Parent.BaseName + '-' + $_.Name }
```

What I am trying to achieve is renaming all PDF files in a subfolder of a subfolder with the name of the first subfolder, see structure below.

```
C:\test\2704814
\Folder 1
|- file1.pdf
|- file2.pdf
\Folder 2
|- file1.pdf
|- file2.pdf
\Folder 3
|- file1.pdf
|- file2.pdf
C:\test\2704815
\Folder 1
|- file1.pdf
|- file2.pdf
\Folder 2
|- file1.pdf
|- file2.pdf
\Folder 3
|- file1.pdf
|- file2.pdf
```

etc.

To get this:

```
C:\test\2704814\Folder 3\2704814-file1.pdf
```

and

```
C:\test\2704814\Folder 3\2704814-file2.pdf
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT inserted another $ExcludeL1 for firstlevel subfolders**

The safest way is to do it step by step:

- iterate the sub folders of test, store the name in a var
- iterate the sub sub folders and exclude unwanted ( -notin requires the excludes to be literal)
- iterate the pdf in there and check that they are not already prefixed with stored folder name.
- finally rename.

---

```
$Base = 'C:\test\'
$ExcludeL1 = @('folder 1', 'Folder 2')
$ExcludeL2 = @('Othername')

Get-ChildITem -Path $Base -Directory | Where {$_.Name -notin $ExcludeL1}|ForEach {
  $PreFix = $_.Name
  Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Directory | 
    Where-Object {$_.Name -notin $ExcludeL2 } |
      ForEach-Object {
        Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Filter *.PDF |
          Where-Object {$_.BaseName -notmatch $PreFix}|
            Rename-Item -NewName { "$PreFix-$($_.Name)"} -WhatIf
      }
}
```

If your output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf` in the last line.

Sample resutlt on my ramdrive A:

```
> tree /F
A:.
 └───test
    ├───2704814
    │   ├───Folder 1
    │   │       file1.pdf
    │   │       file2.pdf
    │   ├───Folder 2
    │   │       file1.pdf
    │   │       file2.pdf
    │   └───Folder 3
    │           2704814-file1.pdf
    │           2704814-file2.pdf
    └───2704815
        ├───Folder 1
        │       file1.pdf
        │       file2.pdf
        ├───Folder 2
        │       file1.pdf
        │       file2.pdf
        └───Folder 3
                2704815-file1.pdf
                2704815-file2.pdf
```

Comment: Hello LotPings, Thank you for the clear explanation and working solution. Works like a charm! Also the check if already has a number is a very welcome addition

Comment: Just create another variable `$ExcludeL1` (and rename the other to `$EcludeL2`) and insert a `Where-Object {$_.Name -notin $ExcludeL1 } |` between the first Get-ChildItem and the ForEach-Object.

Comment: Sorry, deleted the other question, hoped you were not so fast ;) changed notin to in and included only the "Folder 3". Will test a bit further and otherwise try your update. Thanks.

Comment: Update: Works with the -in paramater too.

Comment: Yould name the var $Include then :-)